# Grafrana: use label as value

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am running the SNMP_Exporter package towards some SNMP enabled devices, the snmp.yml is generated via the generator tool.
Now this is a value that is stored in Prometheus:

```
RefclockOffset{instance="10.0.2.8",job="snmp",RefclockOffset="-0.001258"}
```

As you can see the SNMP_Exporter stores the float value inside a label.
How can i plot this in grafana?

I am no power-user.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find what MIB this is coming from, but this is due to the MIB exposing the value as a string.

You can add an override to your module in your generator.yml to extract the float from the string:

```
 overrides:
   RefclockOffset:
     regex_extracts:
       '': 
         - regex: '(.*)'
           value: '$1'
```

Comment: This is coming from a Meinberg NTP server MIB.
Is there no way to due some fancy stuff in prometheus or grafana instead? took me 6 days to get the snmp.yml generated :D

Comment: You have to fix the data in the snmp_exporter/generator.